# Pandas - column of list values (str type) - find matches with any element of another list (also str type)

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have the following Pandas df called `pro`:

```
    property    name
0   too         Deliveroo
1   bar         Gousto
2   baz         Gousto
3   foobar      Deliveroo
4   too         Gousto
5   foobaz      Deliveroo
```

When applying the following code:

```
property = pro.groupby('name')['property'].apply(list).reset_index(name='property')
```

I get the *property* df:

```
    name        property
0   Deliveroo   [too,foobar,foobaz]
1   Gousto      [bar,baz,too]
```

I would like to check if elements from a list are a match for any of the lists in the `property['property']` column, e.g.

`check = ['bar']` Should find "bar" in the row 1 of the df.

`check = ['bar','baz']` Should find "bar" and "baz" in the row 1 of the df.

`check = ['too']` Should find "too" in the rows 0 and 1 of the df.

`check = ['foobar']` Should find "foobar" in the row 0 of the df.

I know that I can for-loop through all the items in `property['property']` (which are lists type)  and confront them with the `check` list, but I would like to do this with an efficient Pandas method. I tried `.isin` but I can't make it work in this case.

The end result should allow to use the `check` list to filter the `property` df.

Comment: please add your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set`, then find the intersection between the dataframe values and the list:

```py
>>> prop = pro.groupby('name')['property'].apply(list).reset_index(name='property')
>>> prop['property'].apply(lambda x: set(x).intersection(['bar']))
0       {}
1    {bar}
Name: property, dtype: object

>>> prop['property'].apply(lambda x: set(x).intersection(['bar', 'baz']))
0            {}
1    {baz, bar}
Name: property, dtype: object

>>> prop['property'].apply(lambda x: set(x).intersection(['too']))
0    {too}
1    {too}
Name: property, dtype: object
```

Order will may not be maintained while using `set`, but I don't think that's point of concern here. And it'll be even better if you convert those values to the `set` after grouping them, rather  than converting to a list.

On a side note, don't use `property` for a variable name, it a wrapper that is used to define the property attributes of a class.

Comment: Hi, I cannot cast a vote yet, but your solution has provided a good starting point. Also, thanks for educating about the dangers of using property for a variable name